# Sharing bindings between Guice AbstractModule and Servlet module

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have an application that can run either as a fat jar or in a container as a war. I am using a Guice module that extends `AbstractModule` on the fat jar side, and one that extends `ServletModule` on the war side.

As all of the bindings are the same, I would prefer not to repeat myself in the `ServletModule`. Is there a decent way to share code between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another solution:

```
public class MyGuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(
            new ServletModule() {
                @Override
                protected void configureServlets() {
                    install(new MyGuiceModule());

                    serve("*").with(Test.class);
                    bind(Test.class).in(Singleton.class);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

This way you can create single module which uses other modules. Sometimes this is more readable.

Comment: I like that; it's much more explicit than mine.

Comment: @Vladimir A serious doubt - When using ServletModule, is it "mandatory" to install other modules here in getInjector? I want my request scoped injections in singletons configured in other modules.

Comment: @LazyTechie, sorry, but I don't understand your problem. All modules which an injector uses must be passed either to its factory method or loaded with `install()`. So you just put your scoped injections and singletons in another module and use it with `install()` here.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the solution is quite easy:

```
public class MyGuiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Foo.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}

public class MyGuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(
            new ServletModule() {
                @Override
                protected void configureServlets() {
                    serve("*").with(Test.class);
                    bind(Test.class).in(Singleton.class);
                }
            },
            new MyGuiceModule()
        );
    }
}
```

I finally stumbled across the solution thanks to this great answer: [Simple Example with Guice Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275194/simple-example-with-guice-servlets).